# the amount of bandwidth between client and server - no articles in front of "client" and "server"?

Tags: grammar, zero-article

> Additionally it frees resources on the server making it more responsive, and it tends to reduce the amount of data transmitted between the server and the browser. This is especially the case when the data consists of many rows of similar data that are to be shown in tabular form. HTML tables are very verbose and can easily double or triple the amount of bandwidth **between client and server**.

Why are there no articles in front of the words **client** and **server**?

Comment: "Hi server, I'm client!"  Those words are being used as names, despite being lower case.  On the cryptography stack exchange, I frequently read their use as names and use them as names, but in upper case.

Comment: With indefinite article, it makes more sense in **such context.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Client"` & `"Server"` are very generic terms commonly used in the I.T. industry. It's the equivalent of saying `"This oil helps cars perform better"`. The absence of articles is fine in this usage because the two words aren't supposed to refer to any specific client *or* server.

Comment: In your example the article is missing because "cars" is plural, not because "car" is a generic term that doesn't require an article.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase, don't attribute intentions to that which is adequately explained by sloppiness. Just a couple of sentences above the very same client (specifically, a browser) and server are correctly used with definite articles.